# SQL server Increment dates in a loop? or otherwise?

Tags: sql-server, date, loops, increment

```
    select 
            pm.pmnum,
        dateadd(MONTH,pm.frequency,pm.nextdate) as calcNEXTDATE
    from pm
```

...

Can someone help me increment the results of the above, until lets say calcNEXTDATE = 2014-31-12?

Comment: That does not make sense. Why not just select the date you want?

Comment: If you are trying to create a table of dates on-the-fly, e.g. all of the dates until the end of next year, you should be able to find examples based on a numbers table or CTE (Common Table Expression).

Answer (score 16):

You can create a while loop to increment days and add into a table if this is what you are looking for . since you question include tags of loop, date and increment you could so something like this

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable1
(
Col DATETIME
);


DECLARE @VarDate Datetime = GETDATE()

WHILE @VarDate <= '2014-12-31 00:00:00.000'
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TestTable1(Col)
        VALUES (@VarDate)
  SET @VarDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @VarDate)
END
```